# man command output full of ^H in vim

Tags: macos, vim, manpage

this question seems hard to search answers by google.

I executed:

```
man cp > cp.txt
vim cp.txt
```

there are many "^H" in the file, it maybe backspace, how to get rid of them?

Comment: http://www.walkernews.net/2007/09/26/how-to-fix-weird-character-in-linux-man-page/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like our grand parents with their typewriters, `man` uses "backspace" (`^H`) to to go over the previous character and type it again to obtain "bold" letters.

While you can get rid of those `^H` with a simple `:%s/<C-v><C-h>//g` you will get many doubled characters:

```
"original
N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE

"result
NNAAMMEE
```

So you would need to include the character just before or just after the `^H`:

```
:%s/<C-v><C-h>.//g
```

But why go through all that trouble when you can obtain a clean text file directly with:

```
$ man cp | col -b > cp.txt
```

Comment: I mapped <c-v> and <c-h> to others, I renamed .vimrc then replaced ^H using :%s/press<C-v>press<C-h>.//g

Answer (score 1):

Those special control characters are probably ANSI escape sequences, used to add styling and color to the text. Vim doesn't parse those by default, but the [AnsiEsc plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) uses Vim's conceal and syntax highlighting features to draw the text as intended.

Comment: Backspaces are not escape sequences, ANSI or otherwise. They are ANSI control characters.

Answer (score 1):

Vim ships with a Man page reader. Add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
runtime ftplugin/man.vim
```

Now you can do `:Man cp` to open a man page on `cp`.

See `:h :Man` for more help.